# Joining a PNRP cloud on my local subnet

Tags: windows, p2p, netsh, pnrp

I'm experimenting with PNRP, just using `netsh` to execute basic commands to register peers on my machine.  I am able to add multiple peers on my machine by opening multiple instances of a command prompt, and entering the following commands

```
netsh
p2p pnrp peer
add registration 0.mike
```

After that I switch to the `cloud` context and enter `show names` and I see a bunch of info, and the names of my 2 peers that I registered through `cmd`.  However, when I ask another developer (who has a machine on my same IPv4 subnet) to run the same commands they do not appear.  I would expect a third peer to show up on my cloud, since we're using the same name `0.mike`

What do I not understand about what is going on here, and what should I be doing to get the behavior I'd expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show Names is designed to only show you the names that are registered on your local machines, not the names that your computer is aware of.

Due to the way that name storage works (a one way hash algorithm) the nodes of a network aren't actually aware of the names that they are storing, just the hashed values.

The command that you want to run is `resolve 0.mike` to actually perform a lookup for the name and return the IP addresses. You can restrict this by cloud as well if you need to.

Comment: When I try that command I receive `Resolve started ... Not Found.`  I've simply registered myself to this same cloud, so I would expect to be able to find myself.  Is this not meant to include local peers of the cloud, only remote peers?

Comment: Ok, after a little more digging I found this link (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/p2p/archive/2007/07/24/pnrp-debugging-guide-part-1.aspx?Redirected=true) which says that specifically you can't do this operation from within the same netsh context.  I needed to just open a separate instance of cmd and try it there.  After that I also tested it with another dev and it worked!  Thanks so much.